# i cant import cv2 , i tried everything and i cant get it to import

Tags: python, opencv, import

I get this error 
it has bug me for the past 2 days, i tried so many ways to install open cv from the anaconda website to other tutorials here online

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-44e890d9998b> in <module>()
      4 import seaborn as sns
      5 import os
----> 6 import cv2
      7 import random
      8 from keras.models import Sequential

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjasper.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.13.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: What platform? Also, what tutorials were you following in the most recent install? Also add this information to your question.

Comment: Looks like a python version issue. If possible, delete version 2.7 and go for the latest.

Comment: I'm running python 3 in anaconda

Comment: I have python 2.7.6 but I had just uninstalled it, I have python 3 in my anaconda jupyter notebook

Comment: have you tried to update it? I think that once worked for me

Comment: update what ? @KalebaKBKeitshokile

Comment: i have both python2 and 3 installed

Comment: @davidarriga Update opencv